# Playwright Timout/Locator Problems

Tags: .net, testing, automated-tests, playwright

im working with playwright since a few months and try to do surface tests on our intern web application
So the problem is that on one day the tests run 10 times in a row without problems and on the other day timing problems and "locator couldn't be found" arise again at various points that I have to fix one after the other, and it just keeps going

for example the tests running through on my local system and on my build server its failing, and its very hard to solve where the problem occured on the build server.

does anyone have the same issues or can help ?

[example test error that occures](https://i.stack.imgur.com/arLcX.png)

[code where the error occures](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f5sho.png)

Fixxed every different Error that occured

Comment: Post your code (C#, HTML example). We can't guess what's going on. If a locator can't be found, it's not on the page. Possibly because the page took too long to load, or a script took too long to produce the DOM elements the locator is looking for. Or the locator selector is too specific

Comment: You can activate [tracing](https://playwright.dev/dotnet/docs/trace-viewer) on the build server to see exactly what happened and even inspect the page elements at various points in the test, network requests. You can save the trace only if a test fails. You can also take [screenshots](https://playwright.dev/dotnet/docs/screenshots) when a test fails or capture a [video of the entire test](https://playwright.dev/dotnet/docs/videos)